# Change the Add to Cart button text on the archive page when item is out of stock (backorder available) in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, cart

I would like to change the archive 'add to cart' button text for backordered items.

I've tried adding this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'filter_loop_add_to_cart_link', 20, 3 );
function filter_loop_add_to_cart_link( $button, $product, $args = array() ) {
if( $product->is_on_backorder() ) return $button;

$button_text = __('Preorder', 'woocommerce');
```

}

..but it removes the 'add to cart' button on the in stock products and still shows 'add to cart' buttons on the backordered items instead of 'Preorder'.

Any solutions?

[View incorrectly displayed buttons with the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPKH7.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'filter_loop_add_to_cart_link', 10, 2 );
function filter_loop_add_to_cart_link( $button, $product ) {
    if( $product->is_on_backorder() ){
        $button_text = __("Preorder", "woocommerce");
        $button_link = $product->get_permalink();
        $button = '<a href="' . $button_link . '">' . $button_text . '</a>';
    }
    return $button;
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! I simply added a class to the link and it worked a treat! <a class="xxxx" href....